# how to use sumifs for date in vba

Tags: excel, sumifs, vba

I have the following code but it does not work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim l As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim oWkSht As Worksheet
Dim FirstDate As Date
Dim LastDate As Date
Dim tsales As Long

FirstDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)
LastDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 0)
LastRow = Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets(“Main”).Range("O2").Formula = "=SumIfs(Old_Products!Z2:Z & LastRow,Old_Products!O2:O  & LastRow, “ >= ” & FirstDate, Old_Products!O2:O12, “ <= ” & LastDate)+Registration!Z2:Z & LastRow"

End sub
```

I trying to `sum` all the values in worksheet Registration column Z2 to `LastRow` and also if the date in worksheet `Old_Products` column O2 to `LastRow` is a date that is in current month then I want the corresponding value in column Z be count as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are to use VBA, then you could use the `WorksheetFunction.SumIfs` , which is the VBA version to `"=SumIfs`.

So the code below, will put the value of the `WorksheetFunction.SumIfs` in `Range("O2")` in "Main" sheet, and it will sum up all the values on column "Z", where the dates in column "O" are between `FirstDate` and the `LastDate`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

'Dim l As Long  '<-- not used in this code
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim oWkSht As Worksheet
Dim FirstDate As Date
Dim LastDate As Date
'Dim tsales As Long  '<-- not used in this code

Set oWkSht = Worksheets("Old_Products")

FirstDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)
LastDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 0)

LastRow = oWkSht.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Main").Range("O2").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(oWkSht.Range("Z2:Z" & LastRow), oWkSht.Range("O2:O" & LastRow), ">=" & CLng(FirstDate), oWkSht.Range("O2:O" & LastRow), "<=" & CLng(LastDate))

End Sub
```

---

**Edit 1**: My preferred version, since you are looking to compare dates, you can directly store the `FirstDate` and `LastDate` As `Long`, and then later there's no need to use `CLng`.

Also, added an option to find the last day of the month using the `EoMonth` function.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

' Dim l As Long  '<-- not used in this code
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim oWkSht As Worksheet
Dim FirstDate As Long
Dim LastDate As Long
' Dim tsales As Long  '<-- not used in this code

FirstDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)
LastDate = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 0)

Set oWkSht = Worksheets("Old_Products")
With oWkSht
    LastRow = .Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Main").Range("O2").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(.Range("Z2:Z" & LastRow), .Range("O2:O" & LastRow), ">=" & FirstDate, .Range("O2:O" & LastRow), "<=" & LastDate)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. just one last question. how can I add + Registration!Z2:Z & LastRow into this formule as well?

Comment: @PouryaAshena does the `LastRow` in sheet "Registration" has the same value as in "Old_Products" sheet ?

Comment: Yes it is the same column as well LastRow = Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: @PouryaAshena and you want to count (or to Sum) the values there ? according to a certain criteria ? it's mot clear to me what exactly you want to add ?

Comment: I want to sum the values in worksheet Registration column Z2:Z LastRow. there is no criteria for that worksheet. only Sum the values in column Z2 to Lastrow. so it would be something like this  Sheets("Main").Range("O2").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(oWkSht.Range("Z2:Z" & LastRow), oWkSht.Range("O2:O" & LastRow), ">=" & CLng(FirstDate), oWkSht.Range("O2:O" & LastRow), "<=" & CLng(LastDate)) + Sum (Registration !Z2:Z & LastRow)

Comment: @PouryaAshena , close, it will be `+ WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("Registration").Range("Z2:Z" & LastRow))`